# AWS Mobile Hub login/registration without using built in Auth UI

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

I know that Mobile Hub provides a built in auth UI that handles the sign in and registration process. But I want to use my own storyboard and process the input fields in it to login and register users.

Here's what I have tried for login:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var forgotPasswordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTF: UITextField!
    var passwordAuthenticationCompletion: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

        loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginUser), for: .touchUpInside)

        loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 18
        emailTF.addPadding(.left(35))
        passwordTF.addPadding(.left(35))

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(goToForgotPasswordVC))
        let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(goToSignUp1VC))
        forgotPasswordLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        forgotPasswordLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        signUpLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        signUpLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)

        AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.sharedInstance().setInteractiveAuthDelegate(self)

    }

    func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>) {
        passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
    }

    func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: error?.localizedDescription, message: "error", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("logged in")
        }
    }

    @objc func loginUser() {
        let email = emailTF.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = passwordTF.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        passwordAuthenticationCompletion.set(result: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails.init(username: email!, password: password!))
    }
```

But **passwordAuthenticationCompletion.set** returns nil for me. What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The setResult function returns void: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/b79dbbc9b1547684092028792c0a17448265705a/AWSCore/Bolts/AWSTaskCompletionSource.m#L44. Are you getting any exception when you run the above code snippet? If so, can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Also, if you are using AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider, during login, it calls the `handleUserPoolSignInFlowStart` which sets the passwordAuthenticationCompletion.  AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider relies on it passwordAuthenticationCompletion object which is nil according to your code snippet. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/3134173c3f79ac1169c569777ca5f0601d22207b/AWSAuthSDK/Sources/AWSUserPoolsSignIn/AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.m#L124